# Docker file content: Error - Dockerfile parse error line 7: COPY requires at least two arguments

Tags: dockerfile

```
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

FROM node:12.2.0-alpine
WORKDIR app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["node","app.js"]
```

Comment: I think the problem is in __line 2__, and the `WORKDIR` path should be an absolute url. Change it to `/app` or your `/path/to/app`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.